# JPAQL concat operation

Tags: jpa-2.1

I am trying to do following to get output like 'MASTHANVALI - Technical Writer'

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select concat(upper(ename) , \" - \", deg )from employee");
```

But having following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select concat(upper(ename) , " - ", deg )from employee]. 
[20, 25] The encapsulated expression is not a valid expression. 
[37, 40] The expression 'deg' is not valid expression. 
[54, 54] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration. 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605) 
at com.tutorialspoint.eclipselink.service.ScalarandAggregateFunctions.main(ScalarandAggregateFunctions.java:14) Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The error message tells you 3 things that are wrong. "ename" is not recognized. "deg" is not recognized. you need an alias after "employee".

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the double quotes with single qoutes and add a space after the closing bracket

```
 Query query = 
   em.createQuery("select concat(upper(ename) , ' - ', deg ) from employee");
```